# regex for a format property=value

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to build a single regex to match this 2 kinds of line:
1)*SBNID=304,MENAME=RV0714,MEID=122,CELLID=4,CELLNAME=LRV0714D*

2)*MBTS_ACN1_RJ/ETHPORT:Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=0, Slot No.=7, Port No.=0, Subboard Type=BASE_BOARD*

The output must be:
For the first (1):
SBNID , MENAME , MEID , CELLID , CELLNAME

For the second (2):
Cabinet No. , Subrack No , Slot No. , Port No , Subboard Type

I already tried: :,=

Works for the second case, but for the first case it not returns  SBNID

I am using pcre(php) regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a start of string alternative to the first character class and enhance the capturing group by using a `[^=]` negated character class:

```
(?:^|[:,])([^=]*)=
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OBWi44/2). Eventually, the `=` may be removed from the pattern if it may be missing.

**Details**

- `(?:^|[:,])` - start of string or `:`, or `,` (note it is equal to `(?<![^:,])`)
- `([^=]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `=`, as many as possible
- `=` - a `=` sign (may be removed)

If you implement all the suggestions, you might end up with [`(?<![^:,])[^=]+`](https://regex101.com/r/OBWi44/4).

Comment: `(?:^|[:,])\s*([^=]*)=` without leading space on properties

Comment: Or, since it is PCRE, `(?:^|[:,])\s*\K[^=]+`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, because it worked if i put all the examples together, but in my code each input are processed by time, so the regex didn't solve

Comment: @user3806586 Please explain what your input looks like. What do you mean "processed by time"? [It will still work](https://regex101.com/r/OBWi44/6).